# AArch64 assembly _printf function doesn't work without \n after the message (apple silicon mac)

Tags: assembly, printf, apple-m1, arm64, stdio

I tried using _printf to print a message but it doesn't print the message without a \n at the end of the message

```
.global _main
.p2align 2

.equ SYS_WRITE, 4
.equ SYS_READ, 3
.equ SYS_EXIT, 1

_main:
    adr x0, message
    bl _printf

    // Exit the program
    mov x0, #0               // System call number for exit
    mov x16, SYS_EXIT        // System call for exit
    svc #0

message:
    .string "Hello, World!"
```

it doesn't print the string

I have found that passing an argument into a string with \n at the end works

```
.global _main
.p2align 2

.equ SYS_WRITE, 4
.equ SYS_READ, 3
.equ SYS_EXIT, 1

_main:
    adr x0, fmt
    adr x22, message
    str x22, [sp]
    bl _printf

    // Exit the program
    mov x0, #0               // System call number for exit
    mov x16, SYS_EXIT        // System call for exit
    svc #0

message:
    .string "Hello, World!"
fmt:
    .string "%s\n"
```

the command I use to assemble and link is `as file.s -o file.o && ld -o file file.o -lSystem -syslibroot` xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path
 `-e _main -arch arm64 && ./file`

Comment: `bl _exit` instead of `svc` when you're using stdio functions that might still have buffered output.  IDK why you added this to the reopen queue; it's a duplicate of existing questions about printf line-buffering.